# Execute raw transaction for ERC20 token 'transfer function' for smart contracts deployed on RinkeBy Testnet

Tags: javascript, web3js, erc20

I'm trying to transfer balance from contract deployer address to another address using ERC20 transfer function.

For local Ganache network transfer from deployer address is as simple as

```
await contract.transfer(receiverAddress, amount);
```

Since Rinkeby Testnet doesnot allow to use method 'eth_sendTransaction' and gives error, I, therefore, tried to create raw transaction as given below. No error received on executing below written code but there is no change in receiver's balance either.

```
const result = {};
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(token_artifact.abi, config.contractAddress);
const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(config.deployerAddress);

const nonce = web3.utils.toHex(count);
const gasLimit = web3.utils.toHex(90000);
const gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice || web3.utils.toHex(2 * 1e9));
const value = web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'wei'));
const data = contract.methods.transfer(receiver, amount).encodeABI();

const txData = {
      nonce,
      gasLimit,
      gasPrice,
      value,
      data,
      from: config.deployerAddress,
      to: receiver
     };

web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(config.deployerPrivateKey);
const sentTx = await web3.eth.sendTransaction(txData);
result['receipt'] = sentTx;
```

Response from the Rinkeby testnet:

```
{
    "receipt": {
        "blockHash": "0xcb259fa6c63153f08b51153cf9f575342d7dd0b9c091c34da0af5d204d1aff14",
        "blockNumber": 8985823,
        "contractAddress": null,
        "cumulativeGasUsed": 21572,
        "effectiveGasPrice": "0x77359400",
        "from": "0x6d10f3f1d65fadcd1b6cb15e28f98bcfb0f4e9e5",
        "gasUsed": 21572,
        "logs": [],
        "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "status": true,
        "to": "0xbc0422d1b7e2f7ad4090acb6896779c56b3af331",
        "transactionHash": "0xdd86d849769e87fef0fd99f2034a5d32821c0dc565c900a5ed1274edbd956b41",
        "transactionIndex": 0,
        "type": "0x0"
    }
}
```

[Note: I'm able to check total supply and balance at the given address.]

```
let data = {};
const contract = require('@truffle/contract');
const Token = contract(token_artifact);
Token.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

const instance = await Token.at(config.contractAddress);

const result = await Promise.all([instance.totalSupply(), instance.balanceOf(address)]);
data['totalSupply'] = result[0].toNumber();
data['balanceOf'] = result[1].toNumber();

resolve(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When transferring tokens, you need to interact with the contract (i.e. send a transaction to the contract). Not with the token receiver directly.

So you need to change the `to` field of the transaction to the **contract address**.

```
// this field says that you want to transfer tokens to the `receiver`
const data = contract.methods.transfer(receiver, amount).encodeABI();
```

```
const txData = {
      nonce,
      gasLimit,
      gasPrice,
      value,
      data, // containing info that you want to `transfer()` to the `receiver`
      from: config.deployerAddress, // send transaction from your address
      to: config.contractAddress // CHANGED; send transaction to the contract address
};
```